# ORA-12560: TNS: protocol adapter error

Tags: oracle

I have installed oracle client winx64_12102_client and configured tnsnames.ora . when I try to login with connect with sqlplus /nolog and then connect enter username and password. 
It gives me error

```
ORA-12560: TNS: protocol adapter error.
```

I have been through many forums and have set ORACLE_HOME, PATH and TNS_ADMIN, but I am still getting the error.

In the Oracle net configuration assistant when i test if I am able to connect to database. the test succeeds, but in sqlplus I get this error

Comment: does tnsping work?

Comment: yes it works ..

Comment: I am new to Oracle. Please give me the steps how to fix this error to be 
able to run SQL+

Comment: Please post:   1) tnsping command as executed, and results.  2) sqlplus command as executed and complete results.

Comment: C:\Users\User1.INTERNAL>tnsping orcl

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 18-JUL-2
017 13:21:46

Copyright (c) 1997, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\app\oracle\client\user1\product\12.1.0\client_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)
(HOST = dev3)(PORT = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)))
OK (20 msec)

Comment: SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Tue Jul 18 13:27:59 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: user1
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

Comment: you did not show how you started sqlplus - with no login?  What if you add the username/password@dbservice parameters

Comment: Yes that works .. if i pass username as  username@schema and the password. it works . but if i go to sqlplus and enter username as username and password , it shows error

Comment: then you still have something wrong with an environment variable.

Comment: ORACLE_HOME is C:\app\oracle\client\user1\product\12.1.0\client_1
  ORACLE_SID is ORCL
  PATH is C:\app\oracle\client\user1\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For client 
I used username as username@servicename and password and then it worked.